# Swift UITableViewCell Separator Missing When Application run on iPhone

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, cell, separator

I am having a lot of trouble getting my `UITableViewCell` separator to work. I have seen the many questions regarding how it is missing and have attempted many of those solutions to no luck...

I have the `UITableViewCell` separator working everytime in the Xcode simulator but when I try to run the application on actual hardware it sometimes produces the the separator(if I run the application again it will show up or if I go to a new view and then return back to the `UITableView` the separators return.

I am using Xcode 7 and creating the app for `iOS9`

Any advice/help would be appreciated. Thank you.